# Computer engines that play Mancala

Tags: mancala, ancient-board-games

Are there any available computer engines that play the game Mancala? I know that there are many versions of the game but it would be interesting to know if there are computer engines that play the game, whether through AI or some form of alpha-beta pruning.

Note that this is different from the other question based on Mangala. I am asking specifically on the game of Mancala, not Mangala. As a result I am not sure why this question was flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The Mancala variant [Oware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oware) was [strongly solved in 2002](https://ilk.uvt.nl/icga/journal/contents/content25-3.htm#AWARI%20IS%20SOLVED). This basically means they have a database with the best move and outcome of all possible positions in the game. The researchers made their database available via a Java applet, but unfortunately, it's offline now.